# Inside of a function the state is always same/initial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects

The remove() function is called from an object. How can I get updated state value inside of that remove() function.

```
const [InfoBoxPin, setInfoBoxPin] = useState([]) 

const createInfoBoxPin = (descriptions) =>{
       
           var newPin = {
                "location":currentLoc, 
                "addHandler":"mouseover", 
                "infoboxOption": { 
                title: 'Comment', 
                description: "No comment Added",
                actions: [{
                    label:'Remove Pin',
                    eventHandler: function () {
                        remove(newPin.location) //FUNCTION CALLED HERE
                    }
                }] }
                
                }
            setInfoBoxPin((InfoBoxPin)=>[...InfoBoxPin, newPin ]) // UPDATE STATE. Push the above object.
       
    }

const remove = (pos) =>{    
        console.log(InfoBoxPin)    //NEVER GETTING UPDATED STATE HERE.

        //Other codes here......
    }
```

This is a bing map Info card. Eventhandler creates a button which can call any function.

Comment: You're running into the problem in JavaScript known as 'stale closures', it's not specific to react, but is easy to hit in react often when referring to state... https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-stale-props-and-states-in-reacts-functional-components/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are referring to old state information in the `remove` function.

When you call `setInfoBoxPin` - the state of `InfoBoxPin` is registered for an update on the next render of UI. This means that in current state it will be the same (empty) and all links to it will refer to an empty array.

In order to fix this, you will have to pass your new state to appropriate functions from the View itself.

#### Example #1

Here, I have created a CodeSandBox for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setstate-example-4d5eg?file=/src/App.js

And here is the code snipped from it:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    InfoBoxPin: [],
    output: []
  });

  const createInfoBoxPin = (descriptions) => {
    var newPin = {
      location: Math.round(Math.random(10) * 1000),
      addHandler: "mouseover",
      infoboxOption: {
        title: "Comment",
        description: "No comment Added",
        actions: [
          {
            label: "Remove Pin",
            eventHandler: removePin
          },
          {
            label: "Update Pin",
            eventHandler: updatePin
          }
        ]
      }
    };
    setState({ ...state, InfoBoxPin: [...state.InfoBoxPin, newPin] });
  };

  const updatePin = (key, state) => {
    var text = `Updating pin with key #${key} - ${state.InfoBoxPin[key].location}`;

    setState({ ...state, output: [...state.output, text] });

    console.log(text, state.InfoBoxPin);
  };

  const removePin = (key, state) => {
    var text = `Removing pin with key #${key} - ${state.InfoBoxPin[key].location}`;

    setState({ ...state, output: [...state.output, text] });

    console.log(text, state.InfoBoxPin);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React setState Example</h1>
      <h2>Click on a button to add new Pin</h2>
      <button onClick={createInfoBoxPin}>Add new Pin</button>
      <div>----</div>
      {state.InfoBoxPin.map((pin, pin_key) => {
        return (
          <div key={pin_key}>
            <span>Pin: {pin.location} &nbsp;</span>
            {pin.infoboxOption.actions.map((action, action_key) => {
              return (
                <button
                  key={action_key}
                  onClick={() => action.eventHandler(pin_key, state)}
                >
                  {action.label}
                </button>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <h4> OUTPUT </h4>
      <ul style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        {state.output.map((txt, i) => {
          return <li key={i}>{txt}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see I am providing a new state with `InfoBoxPin` value to a function named `eventHandler` for `onclick` event listener of a button.

And then in that function, I can use the new `InfoBoxPin` value from state how I need it.

#### Example #2 (ES6)

In this example, I am using a bit different structure for App - using class (ES6)

By using a class for App, we can manipulate App state using different methods.

1. `func.bind(this)` can be used on defined function on initialization
2. `func.call(this)` can be used to call a dynamic function without arguments
3. `func.apply(this, [args])` can be used to call a dynamic function with arguments

CodeSandBox Link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setstate-example-using-class-cz2u4?file=/src/App.js

Code Snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      InfoBoxPin: [],
      pinName: ""
    };

    /* ------------ method #1 using .bind(this) ------------ */
    this.setPinName = this.setPinName.bind(this);
  }

  remove(key) {
    this.state.InfoBoxPin.splice(key, 1);
    this.setState({ InfoBoxPin: this.state.InfoBoxPin });
  }

  add(pinName) {
    this.state.InfoBoxPin.push(pinName);
    this.setState({ InfoBoxPin: this.state.InfoBoxPin });
  }

  processPinNameAndAdd() {
    let pinName = this.state.pinName.trim();

    if (pinName === "") pinName = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);

    this.add(pinName);
  }

  setPinName(event) {
    this.setState({ pinName: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shopping-list">
        <h1>Pin List</h1>
        <p>Hit "Add New Pin" button.</p>
        <p>(Optional) Provide your own name for the pin</p>

        <input
          onInput={this.setPinName}
          value={this.state.pinName}
          placeholder="Custom name"
        ></input>

        {/* ------------ method #2 using .call(this) ------------ */}
        <button onClick={() => this.processPinNameAndAdd.call(this)}>
          Add new Pin
        </button>

        <ul>
          {this.state.InfoBoxPin.map((pin, pinKey) => {
            return (
              <li key={pinKey}>
                <div>pin: {pin}</div>

                {/* ------------ method #3 using .apply(this, [args]) ------------ */}
                <button onClick={() => this.remove.apply(this, [pinKey])}>
                  Delete Pin
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### Example #3 (ES6) without access to the created element

This example will show how to handle callbacks from third-party libraries with our own arguments and state data from the event of an auto-generated HTML element

CodeSandBox Link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setstate-example-using-class-no-element-control-lcz5d?file=/src/App.js

Code Snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      InfoBoxPin: [],
      lastPinId: 0,
      pinName: ""
    };

    this.setPinName = this.setPinName.bind(this);
  }

  remove(id) {
    let keyToRemove = null;

    this.state.InfoBoxPin.forEach((pin, key) => {
      if (pin.id === id) keyToRemove = key;
    });

    this.state.InfoBoxPin.splice(keyToRemove, 1);
    this.setState({ InfoBoxPin: this.state.InfoBoxPin });
  }

  add(data, id) {
    this.state.InfoBoxPin.push({ id: id, data: data });
    this.setState({
      InfoBoxPin: this.state.InfoBoxPin,
      lastPinId: id
    });
  }

  processPinNameAndAdd() {
    let pinName = this.state.pinName.trim();

    if (pinName === "") pinName = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);

    var newPinId = this.state.lastPinId + 1;

    var newPin = {
      location: pinName,
      addHandler: "mouseover",
      infoboxOption: {
        title: "Comment",
        description: "No comment Added",
        actions: [
          {
            label: "Remove Pin #" + newPinId,
            // [ES6 class only] using () => func() for callback function
            // By doing so we don't need to use bind,call,apply to pass class ref [this] to a function.
            eventHandler: () => this.remove(newPinId)
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    this.add(newPin, newPinId);
  }

  setPinName(event) {
    this.setState({ pinName: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shopping-list">
        <h1>Pin List</h1>
        <p>Hit "Add New Pin" button.</p>
        <p>(Optional) Provide your own name for the pin</p>

        <input onInput={this.setPinName} value={this.state.pinName}></input>

        {/* 
          [ES6 class only] Using {() => func()} for event handler.
          By doing so we don't need to use func.bind(this) for passing class ref at constructor 
        */}
        <button onClick={() => this.processPinNameAndAdd()}>Add new Pin</button>

        <ul>
          {this.state.InfoBoxPin.map((pin, pKey) => {
            return (
              <li key={pKey}>
                <div>pin: {pin.data.location}</div>

                {pin.data.infoboxOption.actions.map((action, aKey) => {
                  return (
                    <button key={aKey} onClick={action.eventHandler}>
                      {action.label}
                    </button>
                  );
                })}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have created `lastPinId` entry in a State to track newly created Pin's ids.
Pin id can be used later to find the desired pin in the `InfoBoxPin` collection for removal.

The most important part how to register your eventHandler is this:

```
eventHandler: () => this.remove(newPinId)
```

Please note that using arrow function `() => func` is important to pass class ref to `remove` function.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but you can't change the structure of the newPin object as Bing map is going to receive it in this format. The event handler key generates a clickable button on Bing map. So you have to maintain the structure they provided, eventHandler: function (){}  ..we have to assign a function for event handler. we cant write Type there. Any idea?

Comment: I have updated my answer & codesandbox example. You can check it out. Hope this will help you now.

Comment: Added another example using a class. This creates an opportunity to use a bit different methods for retrieving App states.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your approach.

Comment: I tried your way but my "key" is taking pointer event.

Comment: The function runs but console.log(key) is a pointer event. The function is clicked from the button generated by bing map. actions: [
          {
            label: "Remove Pin",
            eventHandler: removePin
          },
          {
            label: "Update Pin",
            eventHandler: updatePin
          }
        ]   
This  auto creates two button when passed to bing map. and when clicked "key" is having a pointer event

Comment: Let's try something else then. I've created another example for you in my answer, check it. This will show how to handle custom callbacks when you don't have direct access to an element (on generation phase).

Comment: well, I am using functional component. and I have tried using arrow function but still not getting updated state when the function is called from old infobox.

Comment: Are you using class or function for component? You can show your latest code then. We will see what's the problem. You can use codesandbox too